# Trouble with html encoding in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I need to convert the HTML entity characters to their unicode versions. For example, when I have `&amp`, I would like just `&`. Is there a special function for this or do I have to use the function `replace()` for each couple of `HTML Entity character` <--> `Unicode character`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Even though there's no DOM in Apps Script, you can parse out HTML and get the plain text this way:

```
function getTextFromHtml(html) {
  return getTextFromNode(Xml.parse(html, true).getElement());
}

function getTextFromNode(x) {
  switch(x.toString()) {
    case 'XmlText': return x.toXmlString();
    case 'XmlElement': return x.getNodes().map(getTextFromNode).join('');
    default: return '';
  }
}
```

calling

```
getTextFromHtml("hello <div>foo</div>&amp; world <br /><div>bar</div>!");
```

will return

"hello foo& world bar!".

To explain, Xml.parse with the second param as "true" parses the document as an HTML page. We then walk the document (which will be patched up with missing HTML and BODY elements, etc. and turned into a valid XHTML page), turning text nodes into text and expanding all other nodes.

Comment: It's done. I've just discovered this Website and I don't know all particularities of it. It doesn't really work like others programming forum. Bye

Comment: I cannot find `XML` class in GAS, there is only [`XMLService`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/) class. Would you explain the difference if any? Is XML class outdated?

Comment: Got "Error: Xml is not defined" in 2024

Answer (score 0):

In 2024 none of that solutions (`XML`, `XmlService`, `html`) worked   for me, so I did it  manually.

Following is my hard work solution.

To use it just call `const fixedString = htmlEntitiesDecode(crazyEncodedString);`

```
function htmlEntitiesDecode(input) {
  entities.forEach(function(substitution) {
    var regex = new RegExp(substitution.entity, 'g');
    input = input.replace(regex, substitution.character);
  });
  return input;
}

const entities = [
  { entity: "&Agrave;", character: "À" },
  { entity: "&Aacute;", character: "Á" },
  { entity: "&Acirc;", character: "Â" },
  { entity: "&Atilde;", character: "Ã" },
  { entity: "&Auml;", character: "Ä" },
  { entity: "&Aring;", character: "Å" },
  { entity: "&agrave;", character: "à" },
  { entity: "&aacute;", character: "á" },
  { entity: "&acirc;", character: "â" },
  { entity: "&atilde;", character: "ã" },
  { entity: "&auml;", character: "ä" },
  { entity: "&aring;", character: "å" },
  { entity: "&AElig;", character: "Æ" },
  { entity: "&aelig;", character: "æ" },
  { entity: "&szlig;", character: "ß" },
  { entity: "&Ccedil;", character: "Ç" },
  { entity: "&ccedil;", character: "ç" },
  { entity: "&Egrave;", character: "È" },
  { entity: "&Eacute;", character: "É" },
  { entity: "&Ecirc;", character: "Ê" },
  { entity: "&Euml;", character: "Ë" },
  { entity: "&egrave;", character: "è" },
  { entity: "&eacute;", character: "é" },
  { entity: "&ecirc;", character: "ê" },
  { entity: "&euml;", character: "ë" },
  { entity: "&#131;", character: "ƒ" },
  { entity: "&Igrave;", character: "Ì" },
  { entity: "&Iacute;", character: "Í" },
  { entity: "&Icirc;", character: "Î" },
  { entity: "&Iuml;", character: "Ï" },
  { entity: "&igrave;", character: "ì" },
  { entity: "&iacute;", character: "í" },
  { entity: "&icirc;", character: "î" },
  { entity: "&iuml;", character: "ï" },
  { entity: "&Ntilde;", character: "Ñ" },
  { entity: "&ntilde;", character: "ñ" },
  { entity: "&Ograve;", character: "Ò" },
  { entity: "&Oacute;", character: "Ó" },
  { entity: "&Ocirc;", character: "Ô" },
  { entity: "&Otilde;", character: "Õ" },
  { entity: "&Ouml;", character: "Ö" },
  { entity: "&ograve;", character: "ò" },
  { entity: "&oacute;", character: "ó" },
  { entity: "&ocirc;", character: "ô" },
  { entity: "&otilde;", character: "õ" },
  { entity: "&ouml;", character: "ö" },
  { entity: "&Oslash;", character: "Ø" },
  { entity: "&oslash;", character: "ø" },
  { entity: "&#140;", character: "Œ" },
  { entity: "&#156;", character: "œ" },
  { entity: "&#138;", character: "Š" },
  { entity: "&#154;", character: "š" },
  { entity: "&Ugrave;", character: "Ù" },
  { entity: "&Uacute;", character: "Ú" },
  { entity: "&Ucirc;", character: "Û" },
  { entity: "&Uuml;", character: "Ü" },
  { entity: "&ugrave;", character: "ù" },
  { entity: "&uacute;", character: "ú" },
  { entity: "&ucirc;", character: "û" },
  { entity: "&uuml;", character: "ü" },
  { entity: "&#181;", character: "µ" },
  { entity: "&#215;", character: "×" },
  { entity: "&Yacute;", character: "Ý" },
  { entity: "&#159;", character: "Ÿ" },
  { entity: "&yacute;", character: "ý" },
  { entity: "&yuml;", character: "ÿ" },
  { entity: "&#176;", character: "°" },
  { entity: "&#134;", character: "†" },
  { entity: "&#135;", character: "‡" },
  { entity: "&lt;", character: "<" },
  { entity: "&gt;", character: ">" },
  { entity: "&#177;", character: "±" },
  { entity: "&#171;", character: "«" },
  { entity: "&#187;", character: "»" },
  { entity: "&#191;", character: "¿" },
  { entity: "&#161;", character: "¡" },
  { entity: "&#183;", character: "·" },
  { entity: "&#149;", character: "•" },
  { entity: "&#153;", character: "™" },
  { entity: "&copy;", character: "©" },
  { entity: "&reg;", character: "®" },
  { entity: "&#167;", character: "§" },
  { entity: "&#182;", character: "¶" },
  { entity: "&quot;", character: "\"" },
  { entity: "&nbsp;", character: " " },
  { entity: "&ndash;", character: "-" },
  { entity: "&amp;", character: "&" },
  { entity: "&ldquo;", character: "“" },
  { entity: "&bull;", character: "•" },
  { entity: "&rdquo;", character: "”" },
  { entity: "&ordf;", character: "ª" },
  { entity: "&ordm;", character: "º" },
  { entity: "&ordf;", character: "ª" },
  { entity: "&ordf;", character: "ª" },
  { entity: "&ordf;", character: "ª" },
  { entity: "&ordf;", character: "ª" },
  { entity: "&ordf;", character: "ª" },
];
```

Here is the [gist](https://gist.github.com/TiagoGouvea/5b709c922871bc0c3a88f142ad55fc4a) with the code.

If I missed some symbol, please, comment here or there.

Answer (score -1):

In Javascript, (I assume that's what you're using), there's no builtin function, but you can assign the content to an html tag and then read the text out. Here's an example with jQuery:

```
function htmlDecode(value){ 
  return $('<div/>').html(value).text(); 
}
```

Note that the tag does not need to actually be attached to the DOM. This just creates a new tag, reads out its contents, and then throws it away. You can accomplish something very similar in vanilla Javascript with just a few extra lines.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't really use the javascript, because I talk about a "Google Apps Script" : It's a programming langage of Google that it looks like javascript but it is not. This langage has the possibility to be executed into the cloud, not on your own machine. I already try your method but it seems not working in my case. For this post, I set two tags : "google-apps-script" and also "javascript" because there are not many people & posts with the tag "google-apps-script". I hoped to find more people with the tag "javascript".