# XML vs XMLService class in Google App Script

Tags: xml, class, google-apps-script

I got help from [a question answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13293135/1230477). But it uses `XML.parse()`. Yet I cannot find `XML` class in GAS, there is only [`XMLService`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/) class.

Would you explain the difference if any? Is XML class outdated?

### Update

Spencer mentioned to switch to XMLService:

> Use the XmlService now

But if I alredy use `XML.parse()` from the above answer code, will not the change affect the code?

Comment: If i remember correctly the other one is deprecated. Should show up in the docs as such if so.

Answer (score 3):

XML has depreciated. Use the XmlService now. XmlService.parse() cannot be used as a drop in replacement.

Here is the function from your linked post written with XmlService:

```
function getTextFromHtml(html) {
  var parsed = XmlService.parse(html);
  var dec = parsed.getDescendants();
  var returnText = []
  for(var i in dec){
   if(dec[i].asText() != null){
     returnText.push(dec[i].asText());
   }
  }
   return returnText.join(' ');
}
```

There are some caveats to this though. XmlService.parse() does not have a check for HTML parameter. If your HTML is malformed it will throw an error. So for the example in the previous answer :

```
hello <div>foo</div>&amp; world <br /><div>bar</div>!
```

needs to be:

```
<html>hello <div>foo</div>&amp; world <br /><div>bar</div>!</html>
```

Comment: the `XML.parse()` patches HTML, BODY and other tags and i like it. I'd rather leave it this way.